# mongodb + add field + using other fields to calculate + get max

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have the follwoing documents in mongodb(1week of hourly data for 2 nodes NodeA and NodeB)

```
> db.collection_name.find().pretty()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("52979bc7ebf1a5ecb120ae65"),
        "Time" : "18/11/2013 0:00",
        "Node Name" : "NodeA",
        "Integrity" : "100%",
        "X_1" : 103674,
        "X_2" : 45,
        "X_3" : 13071,
        "X_4" : 103626,
        "X_5" : 46,
        "X_6" : 14639
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("52979bc7ebf1a5ecb120ae66"),
        "Time" : "18/11/2013 0:00",
        "Node Name" : "NodeB",
        "Integrity" : "100%",
        "X_1" : 103674,
        "X_2" : 45,
        "X_3" : 13071,
        "X_4" : 103626,
        "X_5" : 46,
        "X_6" : 14639
}

... 

{
        "_id" : ObjectId("52979bc7ebf1a5ecb120ae67"),
        "Time" : "24/11/2013 23:00",
        "Node Name" : "NodeA",
        "Integrity" : "100%",
        "X_1" : 103674,
        "X_2" : 45,
        "X_3" : 13071,
        "X_4" : 103626,
        "X_5" : 46,
        "X_6" : 14639
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("52979bc7ebf1a5ecb120ae68"),
        "Time" : "24/11/2013 23:00",
        "Node Name" : "NodeB",
        "Integrity" : "100%",
        "X_1" : 103674,
        "X_2" : 45,
        "X_3" : 13071,
        "X_4" : 103626,
        "X_5" : 46,
        "X_6" : 14639
}
```

Now what I want to do is create a new field with something like this:

```
db.students.update({},{$set :{"new_field_name":<values_of_new_dieldname>}},{upsert:false,multi:true})
```

in the `<values_of_new_dieldname>` I want to  do (X_1 + X_3)*8/3600, lets call it calcA, which will give something like:(I don't care for X1->x6 at this stage)

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("52979bc7ebf1a5ecb120ae91"),
        "Time" : "24/11/2013 23:00",
        "Node Name" : "NodeA",
        "new_field_name": calcA
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("52979bc7ebf1a5ecb120ae90"),
        "Time" : "24/11/2013 23:00",
        "Node Name" : "NodeB",
        "new_field_name": calcA
}
```

and then I want to combine the "Node Names" to get the sum of "new_field_name" which will give something like:

```
_id {

        "Time" : "24/11/2013 23:00",
        "field_name": calcA + calcA  (from NodeA and NodeB)
}
```

so then I will have one of these for every hour from "18/11/2013 0:00" -> "24/11/2013 23:00" for this example.

and then I want to get the max of the "fieldname"

well that's what I am trying to do, I hope it's clear. I am currently looking at using the aggregation method to try and achieve this. would I be right with this approach.

thanks

Comment: This question is very specific. A smaller use-case would be better.

Comment: You really don't want to store your Time in what I guess is MM/DD/YYYY. Use ISODate().

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this.

```
db.yourcollection.aggregate(
{ $group:
  {
    _id:"$Time",
        x1sum: {$sum:"$X_1"},
    X3sum: {$sum:"$X_3"}
  }
},

{ $project:
  {
    _id:1,
    calculation: {$divide:[[{$multiply:[{$add:["$x1sum","$x2sum"]},8}],3600]
  }  

});
```

Please recheck the sintax, because I can't test it rigth now, and it is writed with notepad and there are a lot of curly braces.

As you can see, it first groups data by Time and after that it does math operations in a projection.

If you want, you can order results with a new pipeline or use $max in a new group pipeline.